# How to display this: row pair - column a value of one row is in column b of row 2 and column a value of second row is in column b of first row oracle?

Tags: oracle, pattern-matching

I have a table of bus details.
It has bus_name, bus_source and bus_destination.
I need to know which bus pairs make a return journey possible.
eg.

```
  bus_name | bus_source | bus_destination  
    a      | Chennai    | Bangalore
    b      | Bangalore  | Chennai
    c      | Mumbai     | Chennai
```

I expect this:

```
  bus_name | bus_source | bus_destination
    a      | Chennai    | Bangalore
    b      | Bangalore  | Chennai
```

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: Have you planned something? Did you make some experiments? If you did, can you print the result? In StackOverflow, when you post a question, it's important to show that you made some efforts to solve

Comment: Is it true in your data that every combination of bus_source and bus_destination appears just once? If not, the problem doesn't make sense: there may be six different buses (different names) from Chennai to Bangalore and eight different buses from Bangalore to Chennai, how do you plan to pair them into round-trip journeys? You don't even have departure and arrival times, which may reduce the number of valid combinations (and could perhaps be used to create a logic for unique pairings).

Comment: Why is that the expected result? That doesn't make sense. If every bus in the table can be paired with another one to make a round trip, is the expected result just the original table? In words (not in the example) you said you need to know which bus **pairs** make a return journey possible. Shouldn't then buses `a` and `b` be shown **on the same row** in the output? That is how you "know" which bus **pairs** do something or another.

Comment: okay, lets make this clearer. It's actually a huge structure. The buses have unique bus_id, bus_name. The number of buses from a source to a destination may be many. The timings dont matter, because the point is "Don't leave the guy stranded there, he needs to come back." And the buses run everyday, so if he misses today, he can catch one 'morrow. Appearing on the same row may not be necessary, just buses that allow the guy to return to source need to be displayed columnwise. THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR TAKING TIME FOR THIS. Yes, i tried. I'll try to show it here when the module is up and working.

Comment: @AishwaryaRajendran - OK, so then your example was correct, just your problem description in words wasn't. You are not looking for PAIRS of buses; you are looking for individual buses that have at least one matching return bus. In that case sagi's solution is exactly what you need; after you confirm that, please do not forget to mark it "Correct".

Answer (score 2):

Use `EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable s
             WHERE t.bus_source = s.bus_destination
               AND t.bus_destination = s.bus_source);
```

Comment: But... but... the problem statement is to identify bus PAIRS that make up a round-trip journey. Your query doesn't do that.

Comment: Why doesn't it do that? :S @mathguy

Comment: Because it doesn't identify pairs of anything to begin with. It only finds the buses that could be paired, but it doesn't actually pair them. Imagine every bus in the table was part of a round-trip pair; then your output is simply the starting table, without telling you which bus pairs with which.

Comment: @mathguy Though you're right, that is what he asked for, so, I assume this won't happen.

Comment: ... my point was that that is **not** what he asked for; he asked for pairs of buses. Just read the original post again. With that said, the OP has now clarified in a Comment that, indeed, he **didn't** want pairs, he just wanted individual buses that **could** be paired, so your solution does indeed solve his problem.